# uncaught syntax error unexpected end of input (java script)

Tags: javascript

the last line is show error

```
(function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'we are connected.';
            } else if (response.status === 'not authorized') {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'we are not logged in.'
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'you are not logged into facebook.';
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Check the formatting of the code and the clarity of the text before posting your question

Comment: which line is giving this issue?

Comment: show error in last line

Comment: add **);** in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seems multiple issues with the code

1. Your first call to getElementById is a error. You should be calling it on document object.
2. Add a ); at the end

Your code will look like

```
(function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'we are connected.';
        } else if (response.status === 'not authorized') {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'we are not logged in.'
        } else {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'you are not logged into facebook.';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this error  solved but one error is show GET http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: That would be because you won't be providing the authorization data properly,